# Why dataGridView.columns.count =0?

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView has already shown the data, but when I print columns.count, the results are shown to be 0.
So, when I modify the columns["page1"].text, it is always displayed as null.

```
var flowsList = flows.Where(a => a.Guid.Equals(account_guid)).ToList();
Flows fl = new Flows(new Guid().ToString(), "null", account_guid, "", "11", "test", 0, 0, 0);
flowsList.Insert(flows.Count, fl);
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();
dg.DataSource = flowsList;
this.Controls.Add(dg);//I've already seen the data in flowsList for form.

Console.WriteLine(dg.Columns.Count); //Result =====> 0
Console.WriteLine(dg.Parent); //Result =====> TabPage: {page1}
```

Comment: You create a `DataGridView`, assign a data source, add the `DataGridView` to a control, and then expect the columns count to be > 0.  Why?  You never add any columns.

Comment: It looks like the columns property is not set until the grid is actually rendered. I can recreate the issue in [this LinqPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/8lfa44.linq). The count only shows after the form is shown, not after the grid is added to the form.

Comment: @adv12, `AutoGenerateColumns` default is true so you do not have to add any columns when databinding if that is your desired behavior.

Comment: @Crowcoder, oh I see.

Comment: You add the grid to the form's controls, but the parent of the grid is a TabPage?

Comment: yes,the parent is TabPage. These codes are copied from my method.it's working.

Comment: Then how does the grid go from the form being the parent to the TabPage being the parent?

Comment: I found that when I was in dg.DataBindingCompleteEvent, I was able to get count. However, dg.DataBindingCompleteEvent will perform 2 times.

Comment: Is the __TabPage__ actually __selected__ ie visible? If not, __nothing__ on it will render or be filled etc..